# How to remove sign "\" in php

Tags: php, sign

I want to remove sign `\` in url

> https://mysite.com/J_yex_N2YKDAfKZjmdoi2zgcIqXYCTpFcmu-kimvM9vC=m22

And my code is but not work on PHP

```
preg_replace("#\\#mis", "", $input_lines);
```

Please help me, thank alot

Comment: There is no \ in the url, I take it you mean `/`, in which case, `str_replace('/', '', $url);` will do

Comment: And what are you planning to do with `https:mysite.comJ_yex_N2YKDAfKZjmdoi2zgcIqXYCTpFcmu-kimvM9vC=m22` once you've removed the slashes?

Comment: stripslashes($url); can solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [stripslashes](http://php.net/stripslashes)

```
 stripslashes($url);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$string = preg_replace('~\\\/~', '/',  $input_lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_replace as below :

```
$url = str_replace("\\", "",$input_lines);
```

Here $input_lines contains your URL and $url is new generated URL without '\'